# PHP/AJAX getting id from ajax

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, database

First of all sorry for the English:)
so hello im a new web programmer and im working on some school manager project.

i have to display all courses in school and then when i click course display his description.

this is my display php code

```
    <?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "school");

        if($conn){      
        $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `courses`");
        if ($result->num_rows > 0){
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                $id=$row['id'];
                echo '<div class="alex" onclick="myFunction(this.id)" id="'.$id.'">'.$row['name'].'</div>'.'<br>'.'<br>';
            }
        } 
        }else{
            echo die("connection faild"); 
        }  

        mysqli_close($conn);        
?>
```

as you can see i gave it the id of the table which i what to display description.

that is my function code in js file

```
     function myFunction(id){
        $.post(
            "api/courses/description.php",
            {  id:id }
        ).done(function( data ) {
            console.log(id);
            $('#desc').load("api/courses/description.php");
        });
    }
```

and here is my description php to get id and display description:

```
<?php $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "school");
if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
$id = $_POST['id'];
}
if($conn){ $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM courses WHERE id = '$id'");
    if ($result->num_rows > 0){
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            echo $row['description'];
        }
    } 
    }else{
        echo die("connection faild"); 
    }     
    mysqli_close($conn); ?>
```

when i click the displayed courses i get the ids on console!
For every course I click I get his id on console.

hope you could help me!
Im sittin on it for many hours and cant get the problem.

hope its readable T_T

edit:forgot to say..
error i have is

> Notice: Undefined index: id in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\project\api\courses\description.php on line 9---cant
>   get id NULL  ----------------------------------------> on var dump
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: id in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\project\api\courses\description.php on line 10
>   (---->id = $id undefined -> $id)

Comment: Aren't you *expecting* the `id` value on the console?  What exactly is the problem?

Comment: you didnt say what the issue was, voting to close this question

Comment: Even after the edit... Is the PHP code you're showing the code in the file rendering the page which makes the AJAX call, or is it the file being called by AJAX?  What are the line numbers it's referring to?  Please be specific about the problem.

Comment: where is the line 9

Comment: instead of $id use $_POST['id'] or define $id as $id = $_POST['id'];  $('#desc').load("api/courses/description.php"); does not provide id as param ... actually you are doing 2 requests - one is useless ... and so on

Comment: You're calling `description.php` *twice*.  Once with the `id` parameter, and once without.  Perhaps the error happens only on the time without?  You don't need to call it twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `description.php` *twice*.  First you call it in an AJAX POST request and successfully supply it the `id` parameter.  This does not generate an error.  But then look at what you do with the result of that operation:

```
console.log(id);
$('#desc').load("api/courses/description.php");
```

You log the `id`, which is also successful.  Then you ignore the `data` response and call `description.php` *again*.  This time as an AJAX GET request where you *do not* supply it with the `id` parameter.  *This* is what generates the errors.

Instead of making the second request, just use the returned value of the first request.  It looks like you want something like this:

```
console.log(id);
$('#desc').html(data);
```